# How to Prevent Scroller From Going out of Box

Tags: javascript, html, css, scroll, scrollbar

I'm trying to get SimpleScrollbar to scroll without going out of the box. Here's my HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
<script src="simple-scrollbar.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="simple-scrollbar.css">
</head>
<body>
<div ss-container style="border: 1px solid purple; width: 150px; height: 300px; display: inline-block;">
  <p style="padding: 5px 25px 5px 5px;">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Here's my Javascript:

```
!function(t,e){"object"==typeof exports?module.exports=e(window,document):t.SimpleScrollbar=e(window,document)}(this,function(t,e){function s(t){Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(t,"data-simple-scrollbar")||Object.defineProperty(t,"data-simple-scrollbar",{value:new o(t)})}function i(t,s){function i(t){var e=t.pageY-a;a=t.pageY,n(function(){s.el.scrollTop+=e/s.scrollRatio})}function r(){t.classList.remove("ss-grabbed"),e.body.classList.remove("ss-grabbed"),e.removeEventListener("mousemove",i),e.removeEventListener("mouseup",r)}var a;t.addEventListener("mousedown",function(s){return a=s.pageY,t.classList.add("ss-grabbed"),e.body.classList.add("ss-grabbed"),e.addEventListener("mousemove",i),e.addEventListener("mouseup",r),!1})}function r(t){for(this.target=t,this.direction=window.getComputedStyle(this.target).direction,this.bar='<div class="ss-scroll">',this.wrapper=e.createElement("div"),this.wrapper.setAttribute("class","ss-wrapper"),this.el=e.createElement("div"),this.el.setAttribute("class","ss-content"),"rtl"===this.direction&&this.el.classList.add("rtl"),this.wrapper.appendChild(this.el);this.target.firstChild;)this.el.appendChild(this.target.firstChild);this.target.appendChild(this.wrapper),this.target.insertAdjacentHTML("beforeend",this.bar),this.bar=this.target.lastChild,i(this.bar,this),this.moveBar(),this.el.addEventListener("scroll",this.moveBar.bind(this)),this.el.addEventListener("mouseenter",this.moveBar.bind(this)),this.target.classList.add("ss-container");var s=window.getComputedStyle(t);"0px"===s.height&&"0px"!==s["max-height"]&&(t.style.height=s["max-height"])}function a(){for(var t=e.querySelectorAll("*[ss-container]"),i=0;i<t.length;i++)s(t[i])}var n=t.requestAnimationFrame||t.setImmediate||function(t){return setTimeout(t,0)};r.prototype={moveBar:function(t){var e=this.el.scrollHeight,s=this.el.clientHeight,i=this;this.scrollRatio=s/e;var r="rtl"===i.direction,a=r?i.target.clientWidth-i.bar.clientWidth+18:-1*(i.target.clientWidth-i.bar.clientWidth);n(function(){i.scrollRatio>=1?i.bar.classList.add("ss-hidden"):(i.bar.classList.remove("ss-hidden"),i.bar.style.cssText="height:"+Math.max(100*i.scrollRatio,10)+"%; top:"+i.el.scrollTop/e*100+"%;right:"+a+"px;")})}},e.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded",a),r.initEl=s,r.initAll=a;var o=r;return o});
```

And here's my CSS:

```
.ss-wrapper {
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
  float: left;
}

.ss-content {
  height: 100%;
  width: calc(100% + 18px);
  padding: 0 0 0 0;
  position: relative;
  overflow: auto;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.ss-content.rtl {
  width: calc(100% + 18px);
  right: auto;
}

.ss-scroll {
  position: relative;
  background: black;
  width: 9px;
  border-radius: 4px;
  top: 0;
  z-index: 2;
  cursor: pointer;
  opacity: 1;
transition: opacity 0.25s linear;
}

.ss-hidden {
 
}

.ss-container:hover .ss-scroll,
.ss-container:active .ss-scroll {
  opacity: 1;
}

.ss-grabbed {
  -o-user-select: none;
  -ms-user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
}
```

[Here's my jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/CoolBuys1290/k9xj6qe3/4/)

Please help me get the scroller to not go out of the box when scrolling down or up.

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.

Thanks.

Neo

Answer (score 0):

To my answer you should use

overflow : hidden;

in the correct place (or element).

Hope this helps

Comment: But where in my CSS do I do that?

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).